# onPressed widget does not working,when ever i click on any view it does not show any splash action,in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to apply onTap or onpressed widget to below listview items and icons. please help me to sort out this problem. onPressed widget does not working,  when ever I click  on any view item it does not show any splash action, what to do please help me.i want to apply onTap or onpressed widget to below listview items and icons. please help me to sort out this problem. onPressed widget does not working,  when ever I click  on any view item it does not show any splash action, what to do please help me.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screen_two.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Screens",
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.red),
      home: LocationApp(),
    );
  }
}

class LocationApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocationAppState createState() => _LocationAppState();
}

class _LocationAppState extends State<LocationApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black54.withOpacity(0.1),
                offset: Offset(15.0, 20.0),
                blurRadius: 20.0,
              )
            ],
            color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.8),
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.settings,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 131.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 70.0, bottom: 30.0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: 130.0,
                          height: 130.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage('images/she.png'),
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100.0)),
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 4.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Alisa",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "22 want | 35 done",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            CustomTile(
                              Icon(
                                Icons.chat_bubble_outline,
                                color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                              ),
                              "Order",
                              () => {},
                            ),
                            CustomTile(
                              Icon(
                                Icons.trip_origin_outlined,
                                color: Colors.pink,
                              ),
                              "Like",
                              () => {},
                            ),
                            CustomTile(
                              Icon(
                                Icons.star,
                                color: Colors.orange,
                              ),
                              "Comment",
                              () {},
                            ),
                            CustomTile(
                              Icon(
                                Icons.android_rounded,
                                color: Colors.pink,
                              ),
                              "Download",
                              () => {},
                            ),
                            CustomTile(
                              Icon(
                                Icons.zoom_out_sharp,
                                color: Colors.green,
                              ),
                              "Edit",
                              () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => Secondscreen()));
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 70,
                        color: Colors.black26.withOpacity(0.1),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 0.0,
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                IconButton(
                                  iconSize: 25.0,
                                  icon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.add_chart,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {});
                                  },
                                ),
                                Text('TIPS',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.orange, fontSize: 10)),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                IconButton(
                                  iconSize: 25.0,
                                  icon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.home,
                                  ),
                                  tooltip: '',
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Home',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                IconButton(
                                  iconSize: 25.0,
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.person,
                                      color: Colors.red),
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  tooltip: '',
                                ),
                                Text('Profile',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.red, fontSize: 10)),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomTile extends StatelessWidget {
  Icon icon;
  String text;
  Function onTap;

  CustomTile(this.icon, this.text, this.onTap);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0, 8.0, 0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade400))),
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
          onTap: onTap,
          child: Container(
            height: 50,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    icon,
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        text,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Icon(Icons.arrow_right)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
//class CustomTile extends StatelessWidget {
//  Icon icon;
//  String text;
//  Function onTap;
//  String news;
//
//  CustomTile(this.icon, this.text, this.onTap, this.news);
//
//  @override
//  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//    return Container(
//      decoration: BoxDecoration(
//          border:
//              Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4)))),
//      child: InkWell(
//        splashColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
//        onTap: onTap,
//        child: Container(
//          height: 50,
//          child: Row(
//            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
//            children: <Widget>[
//              Row(
//                children: <Widget>[
//                  icon,
//                  Padding(
//                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
//                    child: Text(
//                      text,
//                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
//                    ),
//                  )
//                ],
//              ),
//              Padding(
//                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 240.0),
//                child: Text(
//                  news,
//                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.red),
//                ),
//              ),
//              Icon(Icons.chevron_right)
//            ],
//          ),
//        ),
//      ),
//    );
//  }
//}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of the [Inkwell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell/InkWell.html) widget, an ancestor of this widget must be Material widget. By adding `Material` as a parent widget of your CustomTile, it will show you the colors. I also changed the onTap attribute to `()=>onTap()` so that your function is triggered.

This code should work like you want:

```
class CustomTile extends StatelessWidget {
  Icon icon;
  String text;
  Function onTap;

  CustomTile(this.icon, this.text, this.onTap);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0, 8.0, 0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade400))),
          child: InkWell(
            splashColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
            onTap: ()=>onTap(),
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      icon,
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          text,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.arrow_right)
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The InkWell in your CustomTitle class must have a Material ancestor to cause ink reactions. So do something like this:

```
class CustomTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Icon icon;
  final String text;
  final void Function() onTap;

  CustomTile(this.icon, this.text, this.onTap);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(child:
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0, 8.0, 0),
        child: Container(...
```

See [InkWell class docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html#:%7E:text=The%20InkWell%20widget%20must%20have,to%20touches%20by%20spreading%20ink.)